# Are derivative functions always bounded on closed intervals?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Is it true that if a function is differentiable on a closed interval, then its derivative is bounded on that interval?

I know that by Darboux’s theorem, the derivative cannot tend to infinity, but what if it oscillates and the oscillation tends to infinity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(x)=x^{1.5}\sin(\frac 1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$ is a counter example. Note that $|f'(\frac 1 {n\pi})| \to \infty$