# Monotonic function on a closed and bounded interval with Unbounded Derivative

Tags: derivatives, lipschitz-functions

> Is it possible to have a $\textbf{monotonic}$ (i.e., non-increasing or non-decreasing) function $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $(a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b)$ which is differentiable on $[a,b]$, but has $\textbf{unbounded derivative}$, or equivalently, which is $\textbf{not Lipschitz continuous}$?

[Are derivative functions always bounded on closed intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067365/are-derivative-functions-always-bounded-on-closed-intervals) This has an answer, but without the condition that $f$ is monotonic.